# How to HGET from multiple hash in redis

Tags: lua, redis

Need to get the same field in redis for multiple keys.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGET Object:100:RATE:9008 properties.status
"OK"
127.0.0.1:6379> HGET Object:100:RATE:9000 properties.status
"NOT OK"
// PLANNING to have something like below  
HGETMULTIPLE  Object:100:RATE:9000 properties.status Object:100:RATE:9008 properties.status
 "OK" "NOT OK"
```

Need to do it in lua, so a lua solution are also okay. But I understand there is no such pipelining in lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a Lua script to do the work (it has nothing to do with pipelining, instead, the script runs atomically):

```
-- HGETMULTIPLE.lua

local field = ARGV[1]

local res = {}
for i, key in ipairs(KEYS) do
    res[#res+1] = redis.call("HGET", key, field)
end

return res
```

`redis-cli --eval HGETMULTIPLE.lua Object:100:RATE:9008 Object:100:RATE:9000 , properties.status`

Comment: was considering to do this, has a bit concern on calling redis.call multiple times ( although usually redis.call is super fast )

Comment: After creating stopwatch, 500 records / call is done within 80 ms. No slowness found. Approving the answer.